# In these phrases what is the 量词 个 doing?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I got these examples from the book I am struggling to read, 《名词和动词》沈家煊

My brain is blocked! I have been trying to understand arcsine(x) since yesterday, but I can't do maths!

It is said 个 is a count word, 量词. What is 个 counting in these examples?

买一本
买个一两本
买他一两本

吃一块
吃个一两快
吃他一两快

洗一次
洗个一两次
洗他一两次

敲一下
敲个一两下
敲他一两下

念一遍
念个一两遍
念他一两遍

住一天
住个一两天
住他一两天

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are quite familiar with Chinese, I am copying the explanation from the dictionary without translation:

= "个" - 用在动词与补语中间，以加强语气：笑～不停。吃～饱。

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%AA

Comment: I should have looked myself, just, this crazy trigonometry is blocking my brain!

Comment: Glad to be helpful to a knowledgeable person.

Answer (score 1):

买个一两本。 = 买一两本。 = 买一本或者两本。 = 买一本两本都可以。

The word **个** is to show flexibility or a softened tone.

In English, you can say "I want two apples", but you most likely say "I would like to have two apples".